# Reading strings from a file to an arraylist with java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read Strings from a file which are separated with a semicolon and put them in an arrayList. Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile() throws IOException{
   lines=new ArrayList<String>();

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\input.txt"));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       inputs = line.split(";");
   }
   reader.close();
   for (String in : inputs) {
        lines.add(in);
    }
    System.out.println(lines.size());
       return lines;

   }
```

When I run it, the size of the ArrayList returned is a very small number. The expected number is bigger.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `inputs` contains the contents of *exactly one line* after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep overwriting the content of `inputs` - so once you reach the second loop, it only contains the data on the last line of your file.

So you should be using something like this instead:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   Collections.addAll(lines, line.split(";"));
}
```

And you also improve your program:

- by using the `Files` helper methods:
- by naming the variables more appropriately (lines really contains the tokens on each line)
- return an interface instead of a concrete implementation (List vs ArrayList).

So it could look like:

```
public List<String> readFile() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:/input.txt"));

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        Collections.addAll(tokens, line.split(";"));
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well... First answering your question: `lines.size()` is very small at the end of the program, because you first loop through all lines via `readLine()`, and overwrite the value of `readLine().split(";")` on `inputs` on every iteration. Then just before your program ends, you add the contents of your **last** line, split up by ';', to `lines`.

The solution would be to move the `for`-loop that adds the split up lines to the loop, inside the `while` loop.

Also observe that you could call `lines.addAll(inputs)` to add all of them to `lines`, then you do not need to loop over them, which essentially clutters your code as it is an unneccessary operation.

This could also be done in the following way in Java 8:

```
    try {
        List<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\input.txt")).lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MultiMapJava8.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

So assuming you have a `reader` available, it is even as simple as:

```
List<String> lines = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Explanation:

1. Obtain a `BufferedReader` instance.
2. Call `lines()` on it to get a `Stream<String>`. Nb. Streams is a really nice new concept of Java 8, read up about it!
3. Collect the `Stream<String>` into a `List<String>`, which is done by calling `collect(Collectors.toList())` on the stream.

And just now I realized that you split the lines itself on a `;` aswell, so glad we have a `Stream<String>`, the code now would be:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\input.txt"));
List<String> lines = reader.lines()
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(";")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The extra step added is `flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(";")))`, this contains a lambda expression from `String` to a `Stream<String>`, where the stream has been created by creating a stream from `line.split(";")`, which returned a `String[]`.
All `flatMap(...)` does is add those resulted elements back in the original `Stream<String>`, so it is a kind of expension method.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite `inputs` on every iteration and end up with the last line when exiting the loop. More like

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   inputs = line.split(";");

   for (String in : inputs) {
       lines.add(in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the iteration of String list inside the loop,before it was outside due to which only last entry was inserted into the list

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       inputs = line.split(";");

       for (String in : inputs) {
            lines.add(in);
        }
   }
```